# Как исправить ошибку, не могу создать платеж в sdk yookassa для python

Tags: python, сервер, requests, ssl

Как исправить ошибку, не могу создать платеж в sdk yookassa для python, когда запускаю скрипт на удаленном сервере. ssl сертификат есть.

```
  File "/home/nikolay/tg_bot_predictor/PAYMENT.py", line 43, in 
create_pay
res = Payment.create(request)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/yookassa/payment.py", 
line 58, in create
response = instance.client.request(HttpVerb.POST, path, None, headers, params_object)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/yookassa/client.py", line 38, in request
raw_response = self.execute(body, method, path, query_params, request_headers)
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/yookassa/client.py", line 46, in execute
session = self.get_session()
File "/usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/yookassa/client.py", line 56, in get_session
retries = Retry(total=self.max_attempts,
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'allowed_methods'
```

Вот код модуля где выдает ошибку.

```
def get_session(self):
    session = requests.Session()
    retries = Retry(total=self.max_attempts,
                    backoff_factor=self.timeout / 1000,
                    allowed_methods=['POST'],
                    status_forcelist=[202])
    session.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
    return session
```

Код выдает ошибку ток при запуске на сервере. При запуске у себя на компьютере проблем нету

Comment: [пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/12119)

Comment: вы инициализируете объект с несуществующим ключевым словом. Пока не будет кода больше нечего сказать

Comment: Добавил код к вопросу, и немного пояснения

Comment: Попробуйте запустить без allowed_methods параметра

Comment: А вообще предоставь версию requests и urllib3 (с помощью команды `pip3 list` или `pip list`)

Comment: По итогу помогло удаление параметра allowed_methods. так как на сервере стоят urllib3 версии 1.25.8 и requests   версии  2.22.0. А на компьютере новее и в них указан в параметрах allowed_methods. всем спасибо вопрос закрыт

Answer (score 0, accepted):

В общем надо открыть файл по пути

> /usr/local/lib/python3.8/dist-packages/yookassa/client.py в

и удалить из

```
    def get_session(self):
        session = requests.Session()
        retries = Retry(total=self.max_attempts,
                        backoff_factor=self.timeout / 1000,
                        allowed_methods=['POST'],
                        status_forcelist=[202])
        session.mount('https://', HTTPAdapter(max_retries=retries))
        return session
```

строчку allowed_methods=['POST'] Тогда все работает